# How to get url arguments in array and the url with arguments

Tags: php, url

I am trying to create website, now i m facing some problems like.

1. Get the all the arguments in one array in php
2. Get the full url with all the arguments.
3. In my url, i have sent two different values by one key name.
   How I will get all the values and corresponding keys. Like...

   http://localhost:8082/file:/C:/Users/Nitz/Desktop/NEw%20Ryt/LOCAL%20-%20website/data.php?Company=YouBroadband&Company=YouBroadband&Company=Vodafone&Company=YouBroadband&Company=Vodafone&Company=Tata Photon Plus&Company=YouBroadband&Company=Vodafone&Company=Tata Photon Plus&Company=Tata Photon

the function is performing some task on database also, so i wanted both key and there values. AND yes, I wanted to do this work in PHP.

Please any ideas !!!!

Comment: than why do you have a JavaScript tag if you want it in php?

Comment: The url data goes into `$_GET`. You should `var_dump($_GET)` to see what it contains...

Comment: @epascarello - ask and you shall receive. I updated the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $_REQUEST will contain all GET and POST parameters, $_GET will contain only get and $POST will contain only post.  One of these is the array you are looking for.
2. This will give you your full URL

   $myURL = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST URI'];
3. Here's some example code to get all values:

   foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
   {
      // $key is your your key like Company
      // $value would be the corresponding value like YouBroadband
   }

Comment: yaa i have tried that code but its not getting second time company..   :(

Comment: Going by memory (and this has been a long time, so I'm sorry if it's wrong) try something like:

if (is_array($value)) {

if ($key == 'Company') { doSomething(); }

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of parse_url and parse_str

```
$queryString = parse_url($url);
$queryString = $queryString['query'];

$args = array();
parse_str($queryString, $args);

print_r($args);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php